# Getting column names from a SELECT

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I wanted to get the names of the created columns from an SQL SELECT query. (My final goal is to create the INSERT ... SELECT from a complex SELECT query.)

I started with the [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) package, but I don't mind to use other one. So far I have this code:

```py
import sqlparse

def get_new_col_list(sql: str) -> str:
    parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql)
    id_lists = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, sqlparse.sql.IdentifierList), parsed[0].tokens)
    names = []
    for id_list in id_lists:
        sub_names = []
        for i in id_list.get_identifiers():
            if not isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Identifier):
                # this print is here for testing 
                print("no id ---->", i, i.value, i.flatten, sep="\n")
                continue
            sub_names.append(i.get_name())
        names.extend(sub_names)
    return names
```

but it can't find the yy in this query

```sql
select
  p.x xx
  , 'SOMETHING' yy
from
  polls p
;
```

I expect this as a return value:

```
["xx", "yy"]
```

How can I fix that code, or what other option do I have to get the list of columns?

UPDATE:

Works well for the example above, but not for this one. Can somebody here give a solution that work for this case too?

```sql
select
a aa
, p pp
, cast(case
    when x like 'TT%' then 'TT'
    when x like 'PP%' then 'PP'
    else 'TT'
  end as xtype)
  as colname
from
 table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sqlglot`](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot/tree/main) library makes this task considerably more straightforward:

```
import sqlglot
s = """
select
 p.x xx
 , 'SOMETHING' yy,
from
polls p
;
"""
aliases = [i.alias for i in sqlglot.parse_one(s).expressions]
```

Output:

```
['xx', 'yy']
```

In case there are any column selections that do not have an alias, you can retain the expression itself:

```
s = """
select p.x xx, 'SOMETHING' yy, json_extract(p.js, '$.name')
from
polls p
;
"""
aliases = [i.alias if i.alias else i.sql() for i in sqlglot.parse_one(s).expressions]
```

Output:

```
['xx', 'yy', "JSON_EXTRACT(p.js, '$.name')"]
```

Installation:

```
pip3 install sqlglot
```

---

Retrieving aliases *and* castings anywhere in the query can be accomplished by using recursion:

```
def get_aliases(ast, retain_expr = True,
     ignore = ['from', 'joins'], _expr_level = False):
   if 'alias' in ast.args:
      yield ast.args['alias'].sql()
   elif retain_expr and _expr_level:
      yield ast.sql()
   if isinstance(ast, sqlglot.expressions.Cast):
      yield ast.args['to'].sql()
   for a, b in ast.args.items():
      if a in ignore: continue
      if isinstance(b, list):
         for i in b:
            yield from get_aliases(i, retain_expr, ignore, a == 'expressions')
      elif isinstance(b, sqlglot.exp.Expression):
         yield from get_aliases(b, retain_expr, ignore, a == 'expressions')

test_queries = ["""select p.x xx, 'SOMETHING' yy from polls p""",
"""select p.x xx, 'SOMETHING' yy, json_extract(p.js, '$.name') from polls p;""",
"""select
    a aa
   , p pp
   , cast(case
       when x like 'TT%' then 'TT'
       when x like 'PP%' then 'PP'
       else 'TT'
       end as int)
    as colname
  from
  table"""]
results = [[*get_aliases(sqlglot.parse_one(i))] for i in test_queries]
```

Output:

```
[['xx', 'yy'], 
 ['xx', 'yy', "JSON_EXTRACT(p.js, '$.name')"], 
 ['aa', 'pp', 'colname', 'INT']]
```

Usage of `get_aliases`:

The function `get_aliases` will walk the query AST and search for both aliases (in either `expression <alias>` or `expression as <alias>` form) and castings (to handle cases such as your nested `case when ... end as type`). Based on your desired output, there two default parameters that can be changed depending on your needs:

- `ignore`: specifies what components of a query to ignore when searching for aliases. Here, `from` and `join`s will not be searched, so in your first example, `p` will not also be produced in the final result. However, doing something like `[*get_aliases(sqlglot.parse_one('select ... from table a cross join tbl2 b'), ignore = [])]` will result in `[..., 'a', 'b']`
- `retain_expr`: In the event that a column selection contains an expression with no alias (see the second test case with `json_extract`), the entire expression is returned as the name.

Comment: It works well for simple cases. I've updated the question. I would be happy if I could solve the more complex case too.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath--СлаваУкраїні Please see my recent edit.